# функция не работает по кнопке

Tags: android, kotlin, background

функция срабатывает при нажитии на кнопку но не меняет бакгроунд и не отображает окно распознавания голоса

```
fun microfonefun(view: View){
    binding.nameplaintext.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext)
    binding.noteplaintext.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext)
    binding.nameplaintext.setOnClickListener{
        var intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
        startActivityForResult(intent,0)
        binding.nameplaintext.background = null
        binding.noteplaintext.background = null
    }
    binding.noteplaintext.setOnClickListener {
        var intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
        startActivityForResult(intent,1)
        binding.nameplaintext.background = null
        binding.noteplaintext.background = null
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас что-то странное. Вы точно хотите не запускать отображение UI распознавание голоса, но вешать слушатель нажатий, который это сделает?

Comment: ну мне нужно разделить одну кнопку на два элемента, а это единственый выход

Comment: Мне всё ещё кажется, что вы что-то не то делаете. В какой момент и что у вас не срабатывает? Судя по коду, вам надо 2 нажатия сделать чтобы поменять фон во второй раз и запустить распознавание речи. Так и должно быть?

Comment: да но ничегшо не происходит, я больше скажу я уже отошел от этого начал делать другую функцию любые изменение в экране из кода не работают тип мне надо взависимости от кнопки скрывать элемент на этом экране, а он не скрывается все открывается в том виде в котором сделано в разметке

Comment: Сложно по такому описанию понять в чём проблема. Попробуйте больше кода показать. Ну и не стоит слушатели нажатий в разметке присваивать, лучше всегда программно - так меньше путаницы и проблем.

Comment: ну я и так и так писал

Comment: я тут пересоздал вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1498457/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd